# "So much so" vs. "so much"

Tags: grammar, ellipsis, so

> He is an amazing singer, so much **so** that he won first place in the competition last year.
>
> He is an amazing singer, so much that he won first place in the competition last year.

The former sounds more correct to my ears, but I've heard a teacher of mine speak the latter version quite often. The internet provides me with numerous examples in which "so much so" is used so I am convinced of the former's correctness, but is the latter version also correct in its own right?

And would that verdict extend to related constructions such as "very much so" and "very much" (e.g. "It was very much so the case." vs. "It was very much the case.")?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**so much so**

Use "so much so" for a quality like "amazing".

Use "so much" for a quantity e.g.:

> He has a lot of talent, so much that he won first place in the competition last year.